# Page Keyword and description strategy for online store SEO

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, seo

I am trying to figure out the best method of adding keywords and descriptions for the page on my online store in order to have the best SEO that I can. I am mostly unfamiliar with the best strategies to use for SEO and I don't know if I'm going in the right direction for my online store.

I have one page, product.aspx that displays all of the products for the online store. It only displays one product at a time based off of the users product selection from the previous page, so the user cannot get to the product.aspx page without selecting a product from the previous page. I pull the product data in to the product.aspx page using a formview. The product value gets passed to the page by query string so the product page url looks like product.aspx?product=product1.

My question is, in order to have a decent structured website and have the best chances to get ranked high on Google, how should I add title, keywords, and descriptions to this product.aspx page? I started to use the query string that is being passed to the page, which is the product name, as a keyword and the product description (databound in a bulleted list) as the page description.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim url As String = Request.QueryString("Product")
    Dim bulletList As BulletedList = FormView1.FindControl("BulletedList1")
    Page.Title = "Quality Sprayer Products"
    Page.MetaKeywords = url.ToString
    Page.MetaDescription = "The " + url.ToString + "has " bulletList.Items(0).ToString + ", " + 
    bulletList.Items(1).ToString + ", " + bulletList.Items(2).ToString
 end sub
```

In a dumbed down question, Is the method I am using "Google Friendly"? Or is there a better method that I should be using so that when someone Google searches any of the products that are on the website, Google recognizes it as a keyword for the webpage and will show our website in the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain ways that you can single out the information that is specific for the page, which is important when you have a single page that displays different products. One is to include the product name in the title:

```
Page.Title = url + " - Quality Sprayer Products"
```

You should also consider putting the product name in the `h1` tag on the page (and only have one `h1` tag).

You might want to put some keywords that are specific for the product in the keywords meta tag and not just the product name itself.

The description looks pretty good, that's what search engines generally display in the search result. If possible it should be a specific description of the product rather than a generated text, it's basically your only chance (other than the title) to advertise the product in the dynamic search results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the bulleted list used for the description is generated for each individual product so each products description would be different. Also, do you have any suggestions on what the best way to add specific keywords for each product would be? With the way I have it set up right now, I could possibly query my database for keywords of each product such as brand, product name, size and some other similar categories. Is this similar to what you are describing?

Comment: @user3841709: Try to put something in the keywords that people would use to earch for the product, but the keywords aren't that important. According to these [meta tag guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en) the Google bot doesn't use the meta keywords at all, but other search engines might use them.

Comment: Ok, I have one other question for you, since I am using asp.net I have used a lot of asp.net Label controls in place of where I would normally use Header tags, and even some small paragraphs. Do you have any idea if these asp.net controls can be read as easily by Google Bot as html tags? Or would you suggest using html tags for as much of the text as I can?

Comment: @user3841709: All the ASP.NET controls will render into HTML tags, but it might not be the best tags for the purpose. (Use view source in the browser to see what's actually generated.) The `h1` tag is quite useful for specifying what's the actual header for the page.

Comment: I may see if I can wrap the label control inside of an <h1> tag and see if that works, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3841709: You might be able to use a `Literal` or `PlaceHolder` control instead with minimal or no other code change, those only render their content and no HTML tag for themeselves.

Comment: I'll look into that, I also just thought about this... since my product page has a dynamic url and cannot be accessed until a value is passed into the query string parameter, does this affect or prevent google from being able to crawl all of the product urls? Should I create a sitemap with all of the query string product values in order to try to help this problem?

Comment: @user3841709: As long as you have a link to each product the bots should find them, but you can add a sitemap to help the bots find the pages that you think is most important. A bot generally only spend a certain amount of time looking through your pages, so the more pages you have the more important it is to keep it from wading through less important pages.